# Is it possible to make GPS LocationSettingsApi dialog non touchable outside the dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, google-api, gps, settings

In my android application, I am displaying a dialog to change GPS Settings using Google API: SettingsApi as per this link:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.

Dialog for GPS settings look like below:

[GPS settings dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUqk9.png)

It is perfect, except i want user to click on Yes/No/Never buttons, but should not touch outside the dialog, i.e. Dialog should be non cancelable. Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not a dialog, but instead is a dialog-themed activity. The behavior of that activity is up to Google.

Comment: So is it possible to make it non Touchable outside window?

Comment: AFAIK, only if you get a job at Google and change the code there.

Comment: Hahhh! thank you for giving hope